# How can I quickly identify why I received an email to an Outlook distribution list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

A president at my company just sent out an email to the distribution lists "EMEA Global Services All" (directly expanding to 16 other DLs) and "EMEA Sales" (directly expanding to 147) and it has reached me, an engineer who is not affiliated to Sales or Global Services, nor do I even roll up to this president.

How can I quickly identify which of the mass of distribution lists is in error or being misused that has resulted in me receiving this email?

As it stands I don't see any tools that would help and am stuck with manually expanding each group/subgroup/subsubgroup until I can find the mistake.  Am I missing something that could help?

Obviously, any solution that involves sending emails to some of the mailing lists is just going to spam 100s/1000s of folks so I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your company uses an AD/Exchange server cluster (and that is why you're using Outlook).

There isn't a simple answer to this, because the distribution list is on the mail server. The server itself uses the DL in the background to work out which mailboxes to copy the message into - rather than emails between mail servers, which specify what is being sent to what list, and needs to be delivered to whom. If it was an inter-server message it would probably have more useful header information.

I could suggest a bottom-up approach - start with checking lists you are part of, and investigating what lists they are included into. As a side effect, this will show up any other idiosyncrasies while you are at it.

Comment: “There isn't a simple answer to this” –– Yeah, I was afraid of that.  Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there are no out of the box solutions for this
You could either write up a code that queries the AD for all the DLs and see where your details are listed.
Other way to achieve this and an easier way to do this is to expand the  DLs one by one and copy them in an text editor and then search for your name.

Comment: “There are no out of the box solutions for this” –– Yeah, I was afraid of that.  But, if you had written “code that queries the AD,” I might have given you the bounty.

Comment: @Scott it has been really a long time since I worked on AD and I don't have that much free time now. But yes that is one way to go with it, it should not be very complex and would be rewarding if you were a network admin who regularly faces such issues

Comment: @Scott that fine, seeing that I was the second person to answer and not more helpful :)